# 'Stepping Threads Scheduling Parameters' is not working

Tags: jmeter

'Stepping Threads Scheduling Parameters' is not working and always it's sending request continuously  without any delay.

I restarted the Jmeter and as well my system but no luck. It was working fine earlier but suddenly it stopped working.

Ex1:

```
Threads Scheduling parameters:
This group will start – 10 threads
Then, wait for – 0 sec
Then start – 1 
next, add – 1  Threads every 30 seconds
using ramp-up -  30 seconds
```

Ex2:

```
Threads Scheduling parameters:
This group will start – 10 threads
Then, wait for – 0 sec
Then start – 1 
next, add – 1  Threads every 30 seconds
using ramp-up -  0 seconds
```

On above cases, jmeter is sending the request continuously without any delay (but expected behavior is that Jmeter should send 1 request for every 30 secs). Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic difference between **"Threads(Users)"** & **"Requests"**. 
In your case, JMeter will initiate or add **1 user or Thread** every **30 seconds**, not **Requests**.

**Stepping** or other thread related **plugin** controls only the **initiation or use of Threads or Users**, not the **Requests been sent by those Threads or Users**.

To take the control of  **Transaction or Request over time** you should use [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) or [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer).

Comment: On my case, Each thread as only one HTTP Request, so I observed that jmeter is sending the request continuously without any delay. I given 30 sec delay for each thread then also HTTP Request are sent out continuously.

Comment: To achieve the delay in "Sampler" level you have to use [Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) available in JMeter component.To apply a timer to a single sampler, add the timer as a child element of the sampler. The timer will be applied before the sampler is executed. To apply a timer after a sampler, either add it to the next sampler or add it as the child of a [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) Sampler.